# Prove boundedness of recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

For a number sequence $\{y_n\}$ we know that $y_{n+1} = 2y_n-y^2_n$

If: $0<y_0<1$ show that $0<y_n<1$ for all integers $n>0$

I've tried solving the recurrence relation, but I couldn't solve the inhomogenous part. Anyway, I thought that maybe I didn't need to solve it to figure it out and so I though if I showed that when:

$y_0 = 0 \implies y_1 = 2\times0-0^2 = 0$

and $y_0 = 1 \implies y_1 = 2\times1-1^2 = 1$

Is this really enough for proof for the statement?

Comment: Knowing what happens for those two isolated initial values is not enough to determine how the recurrence behaves elsewhere.

Comment: $y_{n+1}$ has been given as a function of $y_{n}$. I would start by plotting that function on the interval [0,1].

Comment: To show this by induction, you first need to show that if $0<y<1$, then $0<2y-y^2<1$:  Since $2y-y^2=y(2-y)$ where $y>0$ and $2-y>0$, we get that $0<2y-y^2$.  Since $(y-1)^2>0$, we get that $y^2-2y+1>0$ so $2y-y^2<1$.

Answer (score 2):

By the AM-GM inequality, given that $x\in[0,2]$,
$$ x(2-x)\leq\left(\frac{x+(2-x)}{2}\right)^2 = 1, $$
and equality holds only if $x=1$. This gives that if $y_0\in (0,1)$, $y_n\in(0,1)$ holds by induction.

Comment: I'm very new in these types of problems, as one might guess. And I haven't learned about the AM-GM inequality, what exactly does that mean, and how can it prove the statement?

Comment: The AM-GM inequality in its basic form simply states that $ab\leq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$. Such inequality is equivalent to the trivial inequality $(b-a)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: I still don't understand. How can the AM-GM inequality relate to my statement?


If this is something that can't be explained very easily, is there any other, perhaps easier, method to prove my statement?

Comment: $$y_{n+1}=y_n(2-y_n).$$

Comment: As an alternative, just prove that $f(x)=2x-x^2$ sends $(0,1)$ into $(0,1)$.

Comment: You are on a whole different level than me. I've just learned about recurrence relations. I'm guessing I used the wrong tag for my question.

Comment: You just have to prove that $y_n\in(0,1)$ implies $y_{n+1}\in(0,1)$. I bet you can achieve this in many ways.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well done! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$y_{n+1}=2y_{n} - y_{n}^2 = 1-(1-y_{n})^2 \Rightarrow y_{1}= 1-(1-y_{0})^2 \Rightarrow 0< y_{1}<1$ as $  0<y_{0}<1$ is given. Now assume it is true for $n=k$  that is  $ 0 < y_{k} < 1 $  now $y_{k+1} = 1- (1-y_{k})^2 \Rightarrow 0< y_{k+1}<1$. So by mathematical induction we have the result.